# Manually debug angular directive in isolation using jasmine (backend-less testing)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

EDIT: Essentially I'm looking for best practices to perform backend-less development & testing.

I would like to be able to manually troubleshoot/debug a compiled directive in isolation of the rest of my angular app.  I've been trying to use jasmine with the karma runner to achieve this, with limited success.

Given my example directive, I wrote a test which will compile the directive and add it to the hosted page's body element.  The element shows up, but when I attempt to interact with it, such as clicking an element with ng-click that's bound to a directive event handler, the 'clickme' event handler won't get executed.  However, if I click the element programatically within the scope of the test, the event handler executes as expected.

Directive:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('foo', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div id="bar" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;" ng-click="clickme()"></div>',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.clickme = function() {
                    console.log('clickme called');
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Test

```
describe('myDirective', function() {
    var $compile = null, $rootScope = null, element = null, scope = null;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(['$compile', '$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
        $compile = $c;
        $rootScope = $r;
    }]));

    it("should", function(){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = angular.element('<foo></foo>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        // Digest the scope to trigger a scope update and attach our directive's link function
        scope.$digest();

        // add the element to the page so I can see it and interact with it
        $('body').append(element);

        $('#bar', element).click();

        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

If you have an idea as to why my event handler doesn't survive once the test is complete, then let me know!

I realize I'm probably doing something jasmine or angular may not be designed to do.  If anyone has any recommendations on how I could achieve my goal of manually testing directives in isolation then I would love to hear about alternatives.

EDIT: I never figured out this problem, but as far as backend-less development goes I've had a lot of success using Grunt with the [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) module.  Then I used the [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) to proxy connections to a my API (hosted on /api) to the express server running on a different port.  It has options to handle CORS headers.  This solution has allowed me to start up a simple express.js server implementation I could use to mock out my real server's endpoints with ease.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grunt, this might help: https://github.com/ekonijn/grunt-require-demo/blob/master/doc/debugging-jasmine.md

Otherwise, plain old PhantomJS debugging could also help: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting#remote-debugging